# Check if a timezone has passed a certain time

Tags: php, datetime

I am having a bit of trouble working out how to validate whether a timezone has passed a certain time (local to the time zone).

So for instance, if the time in London has passed 18:00:00

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$datetime1->setTimezone($tz); // calculates with new TZ now

if ($datetime1->format('H:i:s') >= strtotime('18:00:00')) {

    echo "time has passed";
} else {
    echo "time has NOT passed";
}
```

The problem with this is that strtotime('18:00:00') seems to be using the server time. 
If I echo strtotime('18:00:00'); will return 1470247200 which is the amount of seconds since 1970 but this will not be the 6pm time for another timezone for instance America/New_York which at the time of writing this has not passed.

Any idea how this can be done?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you get the answer ? If Yes make sure to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
if ($datetime1->format('H:i:s') >= '18:00:00') {
```

The left side is a string, and every component contains leading zeros, so you can just do a string comparison with the right side.

(This assumes that you consider midnight of the next day to not have "passed" 18:00:00.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime`'s own comparison feature since it includes time zone support:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$datetime1->setTimezone($tz); // calculates with new TZ now

$datetime2 = new \DateTime('18:00:00', $tz);

if ($datetime1 >= sdatetime2) {    
    echo "time has passed";
} else {
    echo "time has NOT passed";
}
```